# Trouble connecting to a local database using PDO

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I have created a database using DB browser for sqlite. I would like to connect to the database using a PDO function in php. My project currently has the php dataBaseHandler file and database file in the same folder. And then the index.php file which the database is going to be used in, is in a different folder (all under the same root folder). Basically right now when using the PDO to connect to the database i am getting an error saying `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'jobs.db'`
Here is my PDO code

```
<?php
class Dbh {

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $charset;

    public function connect() {
        $this->servername = 'localhost';
        $this->usernamae = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbname = 'jobs.db';
        $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->usernamae, $this->password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
        }

        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->usernamae, $this->password);
        return $pdo;
    }

}
?>
```

And here is a photo of my folder structure, showing where the database file is relative to the DataBaseHandler file is.[Website Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3l1N.png)

I should also mention that my code is being run through XAMPP.

Comment: If it's sqlite, why are you trying to connect to it using a mysql DSN?

Comment: @Barmar as i said in my post, i am brand new to SQL and PHP so i have no idea what i am doing lol. What should i be doing instead to fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What does it have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something similar to `$dsn = "sqlite:" . $this->dbname;` to connect to the SQLite database file.